# Arduino special characters

Tags: arduino, lcd, u8glib

I am having some trouble getting special characters to print using the u8glib. The problem I am having is figuring out what the escape code is for the character I would like to display. I found out that "\260" will give me the degree symbol (°), the part that is confusing me is that should be char(176) where does the 260 come from? I just happened across that code in a sample.

Answer (score 0):

The u8glib is going by the Octal value. So for the °, Hex = B0, Dec = 176, Oct = 260